# How to get information about new citations in Google Scholar without making profile public

Tags: google-scholar

Once per week I check my Google Scholar profile and I can see my citations count is increased. I would like to know, to which papers/works my increase in the number of citations is related to. How can I know this without making my profile public?

Comment: Help about a specific product/service isn't considered OT?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not want to make your Scholar profile public?  You don't need to provide a picture, a web address, or a public email address, and your name is already on your papers.

Comment: I created a Google Scholar account so that my research is *visible*. I wonder why someone would need to hide that.

Comment: A not-so-portable-and-possibly-glitchy-idea might be to create a little program that scans your Google Scholar page every so often and checks for which citation counts have gone up.  You can then search for papers that cite those papers in particular (rather than having to search for all of your papers).

Comment: yes, that is the best option, how would one do that?

Answer (score 7):

Well, the easiest way is to create a public profile, because then you can adopt the solution suggested by Dmitry. (The [Google Scholar help](https://scholar.google.no/intl/en/scholar/help.html#alerts) implies the public profile is necessary.)

Otherwise, you can set up an alert for each article independently (by following the directions in [the same help document](https://scholar.google.no/intl/en/scholar/help.html#alerts)):

1. Find the paper that you wish to monitor, say by searching for it by title.
2. Click on the "cited by xxx" link.
3. Create an alert by clicking the large envelope on the bottom of the left-hand panel.

If there are no articles yet citing it, then you can hack the following link: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=15621263267746567439, where you must change *cites=xxx* to the cluster id of the paper you want to monitor. For my articles, I can see the cluster id of each paper in the url when I look at details of the paper, but I do not know how to find that for papers that are not connected to a public profile. Nonetheless, if any of your co-authors have public profiles, you can use this approach by navigating to the paper details from their profiles.

Answer (score 6):

You can set an alert on "New citations to my articles" and receive this information by email.

Comment: Yes. But I do not want to make my profile public. Is it there any other way?